# setText() display and serial communication (jSSC)

Tags: java, netbeans, arduino

i am trying to read the UID of an RFID and send it to Netbeans but when i try to display the String, it display only the last bit of it.
for example, when i scanned an RFID, the UID is C945AA2A, but when displayed on the textfield, it only shows 2A or sometimes A only. what should i do to display the complete uid in a textfield? and i want the arduino to send data once and won't send anything even if an new rfid is scanned

Here is the Arduino Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10         // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);        // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();     // Init MFRC522

    //mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();    // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
    //Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks..."));
}

void loop() {
    // Look for new cards
  String code = "";
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }
    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
      code += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" :"");
      code += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
  }
  code.toUpperCase();
  Serial.println(code);
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
}
```

and here is the Netbeans code:

```
    public void detectPort(){
    String ports = getPortNames();
    SerialPort sPort = new SerialPort(ports);
    try{
        sPort.openPort();
        sPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        sPort.setEventsMask(MASK_RXCHAR);
        sPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) -> {
            if(serialPortEvent.isRXCHAR()){
                try{
                    String st = sPort.readString();
                    jTextField1.setText(st);
                    jLabel2.setText(st);
               }catch(SerialPortException ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(SerialTest.class.getName())
                         .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }   
            }
        });

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}    

 public String getPortNames(){
    String defport = "";
    String[] ports = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    for(String name: ports){
        for(int i = 0; i < ports.length; i++){
            jLabel1.setText(ports[i]);
            defport = ports[i];
        }
    }        
    return defport;                
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is at:

```
jTextField1.setText(st);
```

instead of setting the text, you may want to add it to the existant text.

```
jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+st);
```